# php insert radio button value only working from mobile

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which was working the day before, and now it's only working from my iphone. I have 4 columns in a mySQL, id, submissiondate, housenumber, answer, hostname

they all work when submitting from my iphone.

If you try from a desktop, the 'answers' which are 3 radio buttons, don't work, and insert a blank record.

wondering if anyone has encountered this before.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $Answer = $_POST['Answer'];

    if ($_POST['housenumber'] == "") {
        echo "<div class='container' style='text-align:left'><div role='alert' class='alert alert-danger'>
<p class='lead'><strong>ERROR!</strong> All fields are required</p></div></div>";
    } else {
        $hostname='XXXXXXXXXXX';
        $username='XXXXXXXXXXX';
        $password='XXXXXXXXXXX';
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=qlfence",$username,$password);

            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
            $sql = "INSERT INTO qlfence (id, SubmissionDate, housenumber, Answer, hostname)

VALUES ('id', NOW(),'".$_POST["housenumber"]."','".$_POST["Answer"]."','".$_POST["hostname"]."')";

            if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
                echo "<div class='container' style='text-align:left'><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'><p class='lead'><strong>Awesome!</strong> Thanks for your input.</p></div></div>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Opps, something went wrong. We will loo into');</script>";
            }
            header('Location: /index.php');
            $dbh = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

?>
<form action="#" method="post"  class="" id="sendmessage" name="sendmessage" >
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="hostname" name="hostname" readonly value="<?php echo $hostname; ?>" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><center><input type="text" class="form-control" id="housenumber" name="housenumber" style="width: 35%; border: 2px solid black;"></center></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><label for="housenumber"><span class="lead" >Quarrie Lane #</span></label> </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
        <br>
        <br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="radio" id="a1" name="Answer" class="form-control" value="I am Willing to do the fence as soon as everyone is ready."></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><label for="a1"><p class="lead">Willing to do the fence as soon as everyone is ready.</p></label></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="radio" id="a2" name="Answer" class="form-control" value="I would rather wait until next summer."></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><label for="a2"><p class="lead">I would rather wait until next summer.</p></label></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="radio" id="a3" name="Answer" class="form-control" value="I am not the owner."></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><label for="a3"><p class="lead">Not the owner.</p></label></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Answer" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: please, do not inset many empty line, one is enough. btw, your sql-query is vulnerable to sql injections!

Comment: is this code exists in one single file?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's being received. And that's a lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: and please, indent your code, just like i've fixed your post. so everyone can read it, not only you =)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why you doesn't recieve `$_POST['Answer']` is that you doesn't check any radios of answers before submitting your form.

Besides security issues, your code is working. But your should consider to add more security to your sql-queries.

As a workaround, you can `check` one of radios by default, like this:

```
<input checked="true" type="radio" id="a3" name="Answer" class="form-control" value="I am not the owner." />
```

in this case you will always receive your `$_POST['Answer']`.

Comment: thank you thank you for your answer, however, it doesn't explain why it works when I submit from an Iphone. any ideas on that front?

Comment: @FreddyMorales, take a closer look, maybe at Iphone you already have checked one of radios. Did you try to check one of radios and submit from the desktop? I'm sure it will work. A little bit updated my answer

Comment: Thanks thanks for everyone's help. @spirit I checked the iphone, and no there is not one already checked. Is there something else I can try to get it to work ? its very strange how when I submit from a iphone, it gets the Answer value, but not from a laptop.

Comment: @FreddyMorales, I agree, it's very strange. But tell me, what did you get in the `$_POST['Answer']` from the iphone, if there is no one is checked? =)

Comment: Oh, btw, try using Safari from the laptop, and tell did you get the same result as from iphone.